# SSIS Excel destination - Formatting Issues

Tags: sql, excel, sql-server-2008, ssis

I have an excel 2007 destination setup and inside of this workbook are four different sheets, the first sheet has a bunch of vlookups/indexes/etc.. along with some highlighting and box borders.

The other three sheets in the workbook are populated one at a time by the SSIS package, this all works great except these three data sheets are being formatted with box borders and fill???

It matches the color and format style of the first sheet.  By removing some of the fill on the first sheet I was able to stop the other three from being inserted with fill but they still have the borders.  I've tried recreating the workbook, clearing all formatting from each of the data sheets, nothing works..

Any suggestions?

Thanks!

Comment: Your excel sheet is being formatted in SSIS package?

Comment: There is a file system task that copies a template I made to make a fresh copy each day, the template has no formatting on these sheets that are being populated, just header rows.

Comment: Do the sheets exist before being populated, or are they created when SSIS populates them?